# ASP.Net Core 2.1 - Reading TagHelper's parent attribute from child TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am wondering if it's possible to access attributes of a parent TagHelper from a child TagHelper element in ASP.Net Core version 2.1/2.2.

I am looking to see if it's possible to have a Child-Parent TagHelper relationship where the child can somehow access one of the parent's attributes (both TagHelpers are custom TagHelpers). To be clear, I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
<radio-group>
    <radio asp-name="radio2" asp-value="one">Some text 1!</radio>
    <radio asp-name="radio2" asp-value="two">Some text 2!</radio>
    <radio asp-name="radio2" asp-value="three">Some text 3!</radio>
</radio-group>
```

Essentially it's just a group of radio buttons on a form inside a single element marked as **radio-group** (this later becomes **div** element with single class, while other radio elements become input elements of **type="radio"**). Since all those radio buttons share the same name inside their group, I have to assign the same name to each.

Now, is it just possible to declare single attribute on **radio-group** element (for example **asp-child-name** attribute) which could then later be accessed from child elements so I wouldn't have to assign *asp-name* attribute to each child?

Answer (score 6):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, I figured a solution to my problem. I was not aware of the purpose for **context** property of TagHelper Process. I can easily assign key-object pair by using **context.Items.Add** method, and then get that object value from child TagHelper by using **context.Items.TryGetValue** method.

Please **NOTE** that the parent tag helper `context.Items.Add` must be in the **Init** method, not the process method.

Process is called *after* the children are rendered.